# What is the difference between a dangling pointer and memory leak?

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, dynamic-allocation, dangling-pointer

I'm new to C++ and would like to ask if the code below is an example of a dangling pointer or a memory leak because it is pointing outside the dynamically allocated array:

```
int * n = new int[10];
for (int prev = 0; prev < 10; prev++) {
    *n = *(n + prev + 1);
}
delete[] n;
n = nullptr;
```

Comment: A dangling pointer is a pointer that doesn't point anywhere special or to unallocated memory. A memory leak  can be made by, for example, allocate memory then throwing away the pointer that points to the allocated memory so it's no longer accessible.

Comment: You could say a dangling pointer is the opposite of a memory leak. One is a pointer that doesn't point to valid memory, and one is valid memory that nothing points to.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That seems like a good, pithy _answer_! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, as Angew says, this code isn't really demonstrating either of them, so I'd be answering the question title, but not the body :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: True. Still, it'd be a shame to lose this gem because it's in the comments!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ok, added below

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sweetness

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the difference between a dangling pointer and memory leak?

You could say a dangling pointer is the opposite of a memory leak.

One is a pointer that doesn't point to valid memory, and one is valid memory that nothing points to.

(But as the other answers point out, your code is neither.)

Comment: The simplest most appropriate explanation.I assure you i'll never get confused again!

Answer (score 14):

A *dangling pointer* is a pointer which points to an address where no object resides. I.e. it points at invalid memory. The word "dangling" usually carries the connotation that it used to point to something valid and that something got destroyed (either because it was explicitly deallocated or because it went out of scope).

A *memory leak* happens when you lose all track of dynamically allocated piece of memory; that is, when you "forget" last pointer that was pointing to that memory, meaning you can no longer deallocate it. Your code would create a memory leak if you did `n = nullptr;` before you call `delete[] n;`.

If I *had* to describe your case with one of these two terms, it would be "dangling pointer," simply because you're reaching beyond the buffer in the last iteration. However, I wouldn't normally call it a "dangling pointer," because it was never valid in the first place. I would call this a "buffer overrun" or an "out-of-bounds access."

Comment: Okay now it's all crystal clear.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Let's make some canonical examples first:

#### Memory Leak

```
int *x;
x = new int;
x = nullptr;
```

We have allocated an integer on the heap, and then we lost track of it. We have no ability to call `delete` on that integer at this point. This is a memory leak.

#### Dangling Pointer

```
int *x;
x = new int;
delete x;
```

`x` is now a dangling pointer. It points to something that used to be valid memory. If we were to use `*x` at this point, we would be accessing memory that we shouldn't be. Normally, to solve this, after `delete x;`, we do `x = nullptr;`

#### Your code

Your code has a different issue, which I'm going to reduce your code to so that we can more easily talk about the same thing:

```
int *x;
x = new int[10];
x[9] = x[10];
```

I would describe this as neither of the above cases. It's a buffer overrun.

Comment: I think it is worth to point out that in the example for a dangling pointer, the `x` is only a dangling pointer *after* the code you have shown and only when you dereference it. I'd add one more line like `*x = 42` to point out that in this context, `x` is now a dangling pointer.

Comment: `x` is a dangling pointer before `*x = 42;`, which I'm fairly sure you're aware of as well. In both examples, I'm talking about `x` after the block of code shown.

Comment: I know, but I wasn't sure it's obvious to people who ask questions like the OP :) The "now" you added makes it clearer.